# How should I name controller file & class in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I want to use two-membered controller names.

```
'controller' => 'about-us'
```

But I dont know how should I name controller file and controller class.

```
About-usController.php
```

Above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename should be `AboutUsController.php`.